# jQuery - check if in array? What is wrong?

Tags: jquery, variables, if-statement

**Hello Stackoverflow, im kinda stucked :(**

I am doing a code where I have some divs with specific ids like 1 and 2 and 3.

Now i want it to check if my number is part of an variable or an array, it should `console.log` it that, that div is locked. But I can't really figure out how to solve this? Can anyone help me?

I have tried this:

```
var f = getXY(e.pageX, e.pageY);
var obj = [1,2,3,4];
var arr = obj;

if ($.inArray(f, obj)) {
    console.log("Dette er låst");
} else {
    if (f) {
        $fields.removeClass('hover');
        $('#f' + f).addClass('hover');   
    }
}
```

I want to have more then one number in the array or variable.

Thanks guys.

Comment: @KevinB the second parameter is the array argument

Comment: @kinakuta Ah, so it is. KevinSteenHansen, Is `getXY()` returning an integer?

Answer (score 6):

jQuery's [`inArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) returns the index where element was found. So your conditional should be:

```
if ($.inArray(f, obj) > -1)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it didn't work. I can still click on the field. 

What i want to do, is so this man can't walk on field 1, 43, 12 exampel. See the link http://jsfiddle.net/6MxfQ/7/